# Upload an image using ant design in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple application where user should upload its image. After uploading the image, and clicking on `get data from upload` button, the user should see the result in `console.log("Received values of form: ", values);` Now, the result appears but in form of an array of items. 
What i want to achieve is, to get just the last uploaded image there, and in the same time on front end i want to see just one square with image, but now if i upload 3 images, i get 3 squares. 
ps: for me is obligatory to get the `thumbUrl` after saving. There is base64 data  of image.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import {
  Form,
  Select,
  InputNumber,
  Switch,
  Radio,
  Slider,
  Button,
  Upload,
  Rate,
  Checkbox,
  Row,
  Col
} from "antd";
import { UploadOutlined, InboxOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

const { Option } = Select;
const formItemLayout = {
  labelCol: {
    span: 6
  },
  wrapperCol: {
    span: 14
  }
};

const normFile = (e) => {
  console.log("Upload event:", e);

  if (Array.isArray(e)) {
    return e;
  }

  return e && e.fileList;
};

const Demo = () => {
  const onFinish = (values) => {
    console.log("Received values of form: ", values);
  };
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    loading: false
  });

  function getBase64(img, callback) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", () => callback(reader.result));
    reader.readAsDataURL(img);
  }
  const handleChange = (info) => {
    let fileList = [...info.fileList];

    if (info.file.status === "uploading") {
      setState({ loading: true });
      return;
    }
    if (info.file.status === "done") {
      // Get this url from response in real world.
      getBase64(info.file.originFileObj, (imageUrl) =>
        setState({
          imageUrl,
          loading: false
        })
      );
    }
  };

  function beforeUpload(file) {
    const isJpgOrPng = file.type === "image/jpeg" || file.type === "image/png";
    if (!isJpgOrPng) {
      console.error("You can only upload JPG/PNG file!");
    }
    const isLt2M = file.size / 1024 / 1024 < 2;
    if (!isLt2M) {
      console.error("Image must smaller than 2MB!");
    }
    return isJpgOrPng && isLt2M;
  }

  const uploadButton = (
    <div>
      <div className="ant-upload-text">Upload img</div>
    </div>
  );
  const { imageUrl } = state;
  return (
    <Form
      name="validate_other"
      {...formItemLayout}
      onFinish={onFinish}
      initialValues={{
        "input-number": 3,
        "checkbox-group": ["A", "B"],
        rate: 3.5
      }}
    >
      <Form.Item
        name="upload"
        label="Upload"
        valuePropName="fileList"
        getValueFromEvent={normFile}
      >
        <Upload
          listType="picture-card"
          className="avatar-uploader"
          showUploadList={true}
          action="https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76"
          beforeUpload={beforeUpload}
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          {imageUrl ? (
            <img src={imageUrl} alt="avatar" style={{ width: "100%" }} />
          ) : (
            uploadButton
          )}
        </Upload>
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        wrapperCol={{
          span: 12,
          offset: 6
        }}
      >
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          get data from upload
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Question: How to achieve what i described above?
demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-pine-hq412?file=/index.js:0-2985

Answer (score 1):

You can gain full control over the uploaded files by configuring `fileList` (see [Antd Upload Api](https://ant.design/components/upload/#API) for fileList).

> fileList
> List of files that have been uploaded (controlled).

A demo [how to use the fileList](https://ant.design/components/upload/#components-upload-demo-fileList) and reduce the list size is provided in the docs too.

Note: There might be some issues while using `fileList`, see [this(#2423)](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/2423) ant github issue for details.

Comment: i tried to use this `fileList = fileList.slice(-2);`, but i diddn't succed. Could you help with this, please?

Comment: could help with this task?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to notify the form to get the last item in the fileList array, through `getValueFromEvent`

```js
const normFile = (e) => {
  console.log("Upload event:", e);

  if (Array.isArray(e)) {
    return e;
  }

  //change "return e && e.fileList" for
  return e && e.fileList.slice(-1);
};
```

Comment: could you help please with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69428679/send-a-request-inside-a-rendered-list-of-elements-in-reactjs

Answer (score 0):

```
import { PlusOutlined,LoadingOutlined} from '@ant-design/icons';
import { message, Upload } from 'antd';
import { useState } from 'react';
**//download - npm i antd-img-crop**
import ImgCrop from 'antd-img-crop';

const getBase64 = (img, callback) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener('load', () => callback(reader.result));
  reader.readAsDataURL(img);
};
const beforeUpload = (file) => {
  const isJpgOrPng = file.type === 'image/jpeg' || file.type === 'image/png'||file.url ===  getBase64(file);
  if (!isJpgOrPng) {
    message.error('You can only upload JPG/PNG file!');
  }
  const isLt2M = file.size / 1024 / 1024 < 2;
  if (!isLt2M) {
    message.error('Image must smaller than 2MB!');
  }
  return isJpgOrPng && isLt2M;
};
const AvatarChanger = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState();
  const handleChange = (info) => {
    if (info.file.status === 'uploading') {
      setLoading(true);
      return;
    }
    if (info.file.status === 'done') {
      // Get this url from response in real world.
      getBase64(info.file.originFileObj, (url) => {
        setLoading(false);
        setImageUrl(url);
      });
    }
  };
  const uploadButton = (
    <div>
      {loading ? <LoadingOutlined /> : <PlusOutlined />}
      <div
        style={{
          marginTop: 8,
        }}
      >
        Upload
      </div>
    </div>
  );
  return (
    <>
      <ImgCrop>
      <Upload
        name="avatar"
        listType="picture-card"
        className="avatar-uploader"
        showUploadList={false}
        action="https://www.mocky.io/v2/5cc8019d300000980a055e76"
        beforeUpload={beforeUpload}
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        {imageUrl ? (
          <img
            src={imageUrl}
            alt="avatar"
            style={{
              width: '100%',
            }}
          />
        ) : (
          uploadButton
        )}
      </Upload>
      </ImgCrop>
    </>
  );
};
export default AvatarChanger;
```